# c++ Queue of functions

Tags: c++

So I have multiple methods with different arguments:

```
class c;

void c::foo1(int a) {

}

void c::foo2(int a, int b) {

}
```

How do I have a queue/vector of these functions? It doesn't necessarily have to be an std::function object, but I need a way to enqueue the execution of functions.

Comment: How do you plan on figuring out how to call each one?

Comment: Using a [command pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern) may be an option.

Comment: What do you want to do with the queue  of functions? what is your intention in wanting to create this queue of functions?

Comment: The intention is to queue user interactions to execute at a later time . I was hoping that c++ had some syntactic sugar that allowed me to avoid the command pattern.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Your question is a bit vague, but if you already know the target object and the arguments to the call at the time you insert the functions into the queue, you can use a queue of parameterless lambdas:

```
std::deque<std::function<void()>> q;
c x;
q.push_back( [&x] { x.foo1(1); } );
q.push_back( [&x] { x.foo2(2,3); } );
// ... some time later we might want to execute the functions in the queue ...
while (!q.empty())
{
    q.front()();
    q.pop_front();
}
```

Comment: if you do not have parameterless lambdas, then how would you then forward the parameters ??

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that you can't.  A semi-straightforward way around this would be to make all the functions take a list or vector of arguments, where each argument is an int, or if you need to support more argument types, a Boost Variant.  Then all the functions can have the same signature, and their implementations will need to unpack their arguments.

If all the methods are within a single class, you could store them in a list as plain pointers to member functions.  That would be more efficient than storing them in std::functions, and more clear if you can get away with it.

Answer (score 0):

Your intention is unclear. To expand on @JohnZwicnk's answer...

A function signature includes its return type, its class object type (if it is a class member function), and its parameters - which means there is no trivial way to make a common 'Function type'.

That doesnt mean you can't assign different types of functions to the same object type - boost::function and boost::mem_function are two examples on how you can 'assign' a generic function with parameters to an object and pass it around before it is called.

If your intention is to just sequentially call each function without caring about the type, look at [functors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_object) or the aforementioned boost::mem_function. Both of these allow you to either bind or assign parameters to the function call and delay the evaluation of the function for later.